# Mapping missing in Intellij IDEA for Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am using Spring Boot 2.3.4 , IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate version 2020.2.2 . (Example project can be found here https://github.com/ehmkah/springbootintellij ) I don't see the "mappings" sub-view in IntelliJ IDEA Services View for my `springboot-application`. It should be right to *Health*. There are several endpoints configured - they are working I see them in the browser. I guess something is not configured correctly, but I only see errors like

> AM    Error Loading Project: Cannot load facet Web in *EventLog*.

Where should I look for errors or are there any known incompatibilities?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question. Let's add more information clearly.

Comment: Oh sorry :-( My assumption was: Open Spring-boot Application with intellij start it and I see the mappings. But its not the case and I am wondering what I have done wrong.

Comment: Please check https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html#spring-boot-endpoints

Comment: Note that it is shown if Spring Boot application is a reactive web application (there should be `spring-webflux` library used in project).

Comment: If problem remains, please provide a sample project at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: I created a project (https://github.com/ehmkah/springbootintellij ) and opened an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-251984 hope this helps Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mappings** tab as a feature requires **Spring MVC** bundled plugin. Please make sure it is enabled in Settings(Preferences) | Plugins.

Comment: If this is not working for you, do the following: Delete the disabled_plugins.txt file from your Intellij configuration file. On Linux you find it under ~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.2 or read https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory to see where you find in in other OS

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot application mapping is only accessible with Intellij **Ultimate**

Comment: correct - thank you this hint. I use the ultimate version and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

use plugin [Endpoints Explorer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17867-endpoints-explorer), it works well with Intellij Community